# Escape question mark in C?

Tags: c, printf, format-string

In the [table of escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C), I can notice that escaping a question mark is required, and done with `\?`.

Why is this required? looks like the following code runs without errors or warnings:

```
printf("a?B\n");
```

Comment: What table is that? Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: Wikipedia, for example... edited the question with a link.